Shadcn Form TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'getFieldState' of 'useFormContext(...)'
I'm using the Shadcn Form component for my application. I have a simple form and schema:
const formSchema = z.object({
    username: z.string(),
  })

const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
  resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
  defaultValues: {
    username: "",
  },
});

And here's my form in the HTML:
<Form {...form}>
  <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
    <FormField
      control={form.control}
      name="username"
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormItem>
          <FormLabel>User Name</FormLabel>
          <FormControl>
            <Input {...field} />
          </FormControl>
          <FormMessage />
        </FormItem>
      )}
    />
    <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
  </form>
</Form>         

However when I open up this form in my application, I receive the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'getFieldState' of 'useFormContext(...)' as it is null.

How do I fix this error?

This error was happening because I was importing Form from react-hook-form instead of from the shadcn import @/components/ui/form. Correcting the import fixed the error
